# What is the meaning of "might well not be"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

We have used the verbal system, but what about the musical subsystem of the auditory system of the brain? For many people the activation of this system by a particular kind of music leads to a relaxing effect. Note that the music ***might well not be*** a gentle flute. There are people who find a heavy drum-beat relaxing.

What does **"might well not be"** mean in the above text? What can be used instead of that phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'might well not be' means almost exactly the same as 'might not be'

The 'well' is just used for emphasis.

Look at this previous thread https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235501/difference-between-may-and-may-well

EDIT

Some alternatives (including some of Andrew's suggestions).

> Note that the music isn't necessarily a gentle flute.
>
> Note that the music could be something other than a gentle flute.
>
> Note that the music might well not be a gentle flute.
>
> Note that the music doesn't have to be a gentle flute.
>
> Note that the music is not required to be a gentle flute.

Comment: What can be used instead of "might well not be" ?     Would you please write several simple example in plain English for using "might well not be" ?

Comment: @ARAM  Depending on context: "Doesn't have to be", "Could be something other than", "Should not have to be", "Ought not to be", and various others.

Comment: What about my context? What can be used there instead of "might well not be"?

Comment: @ARAM *it's (quite) possible that the music isn't . . .*